# I have Lat/Long coordinates, and an address.. Is possible to get a link to google maps with that info?

Tags: android

I want to create a hyper-link for google maps with either the Address or the Lat/Long coordinates.  Is this possible to do with Android (Using Android Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Static Maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/. Your URL (hyperlink) will take the form:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?<parameters>`

where `<parameters>` are things like `center`, `zoom`, etc.  Here's a simple example using lat/long:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.7658328,-73.9758611&size=400x400&zoom=14
```